# how to print output of affected rows with powershell sqlserver smo assembly

Tags: powershell

Hi everyone i am new to powershell. im looking for a script that will print out the affected rows from an UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE tsql using smo assembly.

i tried searching on the net and find some solution which is written from C#.. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eb9071c9-c8c2-47db-b660-2ad044af0ede/how-do-i-get-the-output-from-databaseexecutenonquery?forum=sqlsmoanddmo
i dont know how to convert it to powershell.

below is a powershell script that execute tsql update using smo.

```
$null = [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo")
$null = [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum ")
$null = [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
$Server = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server
$db = $server.Databases["TESTDB"]
$result = $db.ExecuteNonQuery("UPDATE Persons set City = 'Cavite' where FirstName = 'Miguel'")
```

hope anyone can help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing from ExecuteNonQuery() to ExecuteWithResults() and adding the select @@rowcount command.

```
 $result = $db.ExecuteWithResults("UPDATE Persons Set City = 'Cavite' where FirstName = 'Miguel'; Select @@ROWCOUNT;")
$result.Tables[0].Rows[0]  # to output the value of @@rowcount
```

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks for your response but i believe ExecuteScalar is not supported in smo assembly.

Comment: You're right, sorry I copied from the wrong file.  Answer changed to use ExecuteWithResults().

Comment: it will not return any result since ExecuteWithResults is used for select statements only or for statements that return results. thanks again for your prompt reply

Comment: That's where the select @@rowcount comes in. That will return the number of rows affected by your update (or an insert/delete) statement.