# Not Getting Back a Count from an Insert Executed by ExecuteNonQuery Against MS SQL Server from PowerShell script

Tags: sql-server, powershell, error-handling, executenonquery

The following code executes a BULK INSERT which succeeds, but it does not return the number of rows affected.  When I do a 'SELECT count(*) ...' to confirm the count, millions of rows have been inserted. I suspect the overflow error is part of the problem. Why is the rows affected count failing to return?  Any ideas of how to get the count?  I have several other similar routines and they always return the count.

**Code**

```
try {

     $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
     $Command.Connection = "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=$($file_info.database);server=$($file_info.db_server_instance)"
     $Command.CommandTimeout = 18000 # 5 hours
     $Command.Connection.Open()

     try {

          $bulkinsert_sql = "BULK INSERT $($file_info.database).$($file_info.owner).$($file_info.table) FROM '$load_file_path' with (ERRORFILE='$load_file_error_path', MAXERRORS=$($file_info.dbload_error_max), TABLOCK, FIELDTERMINATOR='\t')"
          $Command.CommandText = $bulkinsert_sql
          $loaded_cnt=$Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
          write-host "$loaded_cnt ROWS LOADED"

     } catch [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException] {

          $_ | select -expandproperty invocationinfo | Format-List Line, PositionMessage -force
          write-host $_.Exception.ToString() -foregroundcolor "red"     
          $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
     }

     # set error preference back
     $ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

} catch [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException] {

     $_ | select -expandproperty invocationinfo | Format-List Line, PositionMessage -force
     write-host $_.Exception.ToString() -foregroundcolor "red"
     $ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

} finally {

     if ($Command.Connection -eq 'Open') {
         $Command.Connection.Close()
     }
}
```

**Error Messages Caught**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1714271, column 72 (PROVIDER_NAME1).
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1714272, column 72 (PROVIDER_NAME1).
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2083378, column 72 (PROVIDER_NAME1).
Bulk load data conversion error (overflow) for row 4633809, column 82 (TF_ME_TOT_DEDUCTIONS).
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, 
TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean&
 usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
ClientConnectionId:ba9e07ac-1bc4-4c59-8a0a-167d7b281644
Error Number:4863,State:1,Class:16
```

Comment: I'm reading about SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF....

Comment: And ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET ARITHABORT ON ...  but no solution.

Comment: One answer shows [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299945/how-to-print-output-of-affected-rows-with-powershell-sqlserver-smo-assembly) ```$result = $db.ExecuteWithResults("UPDATE Persons Set City = 'Cavite' where FirstName = 'Miguel'; Select @@ROWCOUNT;")
$result.Tables[0].Rows[0]  # to output the value of @@rowcount```  But I shouldn't have to use that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the rows affected count failing to return? Any ideas of how to get the count?

ExecuteNonQuery is not the "lowest level" method for running a query.  It makes some simplifying assumptions about what information SQL Server might return.

When running a query from the client SQL Server can return any combination of Error messages, Row-count messages, and result sets.  But to simplify things for the normal case, SqlClient throws a SqlException when it sees an error message, and so ExecuteNonQuery doesn't even return (let alone return a rowcount).

If you want ExecuteNonQuery to return, you can redirect all error messages to an event handler, and supress the .NET Exception throwing behavior with [SqlConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.fireinfomessageeventonusererrors?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @[David Browne - Microsoft]The SqlConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors accomplishes the redirection and suppresses too?  I'll look into that.  Do you have a lower level method for executing such queries that you prefer or recommend?  I've been having pretty good success with ExecuteNonQuery until this surprise.

Comment: `FireInfoMessageEventOnUserError` supresses SqlExceptions that result from error messages sent from the server, but not from things like network errors. 
 `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` gives you access to the individual resultsets and rowcounts, and combined with `FireInfoMessageEventOnUserError` provides the lowest-level API available in SqlClient.

Comment: Yes, I noticed in the documentation it mentions "An error with a severity level of 17 or above that causes the server to stop processing the command needs to be handled as an exception. In this case, an exception is thrown regardless of how the error is handled in the InfoMessage event."  That's a bummer because I would like to decide what to do for identifiable errors.  At least that's my story ....

Comment: @[David Browne - Microsoft]One other thing, I thought with an overflow there would be an abort and rollback?  It completes the insert and only fails the one overflow record.  Can you explain that behavior or is that a separate question?

Comment: Different question.  But it's complex.  Read this: http://sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html